# Obtaining data in two individual methods

Tags: java, caching, methods, hashmap

I have a project which include two different static main methods. That is I need to run them individually for my purpose. Note that these two methods must be executed separately from one another. I run first method lets call it as "getA". the getA method simply stores all the unique data into HashMap and it accomplishes its job. Afterwards, I am ready to execute the getB method but the point is that I need to the hashmap in which I put all the data using getA method, whereas I couldn't figure it out how to reach this hashmap from the getB method because these methods are unique and only this hashmap is related to each other. Actually I perhaps need some caching stuff to make them possible.

Let me illustrate with an example:

```
-------- start getA method
-------- store data into hashmap
-------- done

-------- start  getB method after (1/2/3 hour(s)) (the getA method must be run before this method)
-------- obtain the data that the hashmap stores
-------- done
```

Note that this getB method might be run, I don't know, after 2 hours. I want to reach this hashmap any time. How can I achieve this process? Should I use external library or as I said earlier something like caching?

Thanks for any advice and approach!

Comment: Sounds like you have two different projects that happen to occupy the same folder. Either you need to restructure your code or store the data on disk somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, good possibility is to store data from HashMap into **database** (or **file**) to be persistent and to achieve your goal of running second method in 2 hours later. Then, even though you close your application, all data will be stored as records in some database table. But, if you do not want to use persistent data storing and you also do not want to close your app and backup your data in this way, there are other possibilities to make this HashMap to be  visible throughout your application (maybe visibility between classes), appropriate method to do it is to set it as **static** and public (or protected). Second possibility to avoid this approach is to use **Singleton** deign pattern with using this HashMap as its attribute. There is many ways to accomplish your goal, depends on your demands.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not an issue here and the hashmap is not really big, then you can serialize it to a file and deserialize from another application. Actually this is very basic persistent caching. Alternatively you should have third cache server that is available for both applications.